# setInterval calling function with an undefined parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has been flagged as already answered with a link provided above. However, I already read that answer and it only answered how to use setInterval in a for loop. There were no functions being called with parameters passed to them in that solution, and that is my situation, so I couldn't use it to fix my situation.

I'm fairly new to programming, so I'll try to describe as best as I can. In setInterval, I am passing a parameter to the function toggleClusters which setInterval calls. The debugger shows the parameter as being correct. It is a reference to an array position that holds an object literal that contains map marker objects. I seem to be misunderstanding something about what values stay around and what do not when using setInterval, because the debugger shows the correct object literal being passed as an arg, but when the function is called, the debugger shows the obj that is supposed to be passed as undefined. Is it that this passed value no longer exists when the function is called?

```
function setClusterAnimations() {
    for (var i = 0; i < clusters.length; i++) {
        //intervalNames stores handle references for stopping any setInterval instances created
        intervalNames.push(setInterval(function () {
        //clusters[i] will hold an object literal containing marker objects    
        toggleClusters(clusters[i]);
        }, 1000));
    }
}
//cObj is coming back as undefined in debugger and bombing
function toggleClusters(cObj) {
    var propCount = Object.keys(cObj).length;
    for (var prop in cObj){
        if (prop.getZIndex() < 200 || prop.getZIndex() == 200 + propCount) {
            prop.setZIndex(200);
        }
        else {
            prop.setZindex(prop.getZIndex() + 1)
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: question edited above. The answer you referenced only shows how to use setInterval in a for loop. It is not a case where a function is being called with a parameter, and that parameter is coming back as null at function execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically the issue with such asynchronous calls as with `setInterval()`. You can solve this in different ways, one of which is using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
for (var i = 0; i < clusters.length; i++) {
    //intervalNames stores handle references for stopping any setInterval instances created
    intervalNames.push(setInterval(function (i) {
    //clusters[i] will hold an object literal containing marker objects    
        toggleClusters(clusters[i]);
    }.bind(null, i), 1000));
}
```

The `toggleClusters(clusters[i])` statement will only be executed when your loop has finished, at which time `i` will be beyond the correct range (it will be `clusters.length`). With `bind()`, and mostly with the function parameter `i`, you create a separate variable in the scope of the call back function, which gets its value defined at the moment you execute `bind()`. That `i` is independent from the original `i`, and retains the value you have given it via `bind()`.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer. Too many people read two sentences and then decide a question is a duplicate, when it is not. Clearly my problem is not how to use a for loop, it's how to preserve the value as you said. Let me try it, but it looks like it will work and I'll mark as answered

Answer (score 1):

that is because your "i" variable is not captured in the function passed as an argument to setInverval. 
Therefore , when this function is invoked, i is always equal to clusters.length.

consider the differences between the two following pieces of code:

```
 var arr = [1, 2, 3];

var broken = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      setInterval(function() {
        console.log("broken: " + arr[i]);
      }, 1000);
      // logs broken: undefined
  }
};

var fixed = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    setInterval((function(k) {
        return function() {
        console.log("fixed: " + arr[k]);
      }
    }(i)), 1000); // i is captured here
  }
};
```